# How can I pass nil to generic type parameter on Swift?

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm using Alamofire5 and Swift 5.7.x.

There is a problem when I receive an response data from API server.

The response data default is:

```json
{
    statusCode: 200
    message: "OK"
    items: null
}
```

But the "items" attribute can be anything data type.
null, string, int, array, object..

I was about to solve using Generics.
But I don't know how to handle the null.

It's API common code:

```swift
struct Response<T: Codable>: Codable {
    var statusCode: Int
    var message: String
    var items: T?
}

class API {
    func request<Parameters: Encodable, T: Decodable>(_ path: String,
                                                      method: HTTPMethod = .get,
                                                      params: Parameters? = nil,
                                                      completion: @escaping (Result<Response<T?>, NetworkError>) -> Void) {

        //some codes..
        
        AF.request("\(path)",
                   method: method,
                   parameters: params,
                   encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.prettyPrinted
        )
        .validate(statusCode: 200..<400)
        .validate(contentType: ["application/json"])
        .responseData { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let data):
                guard let decodedData = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response<T?>.self, from: data) else { return }
                print(decodedData)

                completion(.success(decodedData as Response<T?>))
            case.failure(let error):
                // some codes..
            }
        }

    }
}
```

It's caller:

```swift
        API.shared.request("/users/device", method: .post, params: reqParam) { (response: Result<Response<This is the problem..!!>, NetworkError>) in
            switch response {
            case .success(let data):
                print("userDevice updated")
                debugPrint(data)
            case .failure(let error):
                // some codes..
            }
        }
```

How can I pass nil on the caller?

Comment: Since your completion receives a `Response<T?>` (i.e. an optional `T`), the `null` case becomes simply `nil`. I assume the `items` attribute always has the same type for each request path (e.g. `"/users/device"` always gives an optional `Device` type). That's the type you would need in the caller statement, e.g., `Response<Device?>`.

Comment: A generic approach like this implies you know the response type upfront at compile time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you have following response for all your API requests

```
{
    statusCode: 200
    message: "OK"
    items: null
}
```

And your Codable struct as following

```
struct Response<T: Codable>: Codable {
    var statusCode: Int
    var message: String
    var items: T? // Notice this is declared as Optional
}
```

As your items variable is declared as optional it will work as expected with little change.

You can declare an Empty Struct which can be used when you are expecting `null` value for `items` key, like following.

```
struct EmptyResponse: Codable {

}
```

You can use `EmptyResponse` struct as following:

```
API.shared.request("/users/device", method: .post, params: reqParam) { (response: Result<Response<EmptyResponse>, NetworkError>) in
            switch response {
            case .success(let data):
                debugPrint(data)
                if let items = data.items {
                    // Use items here
                } else {
                    // Items is nil
                }

            case .failure(let error):
                // some codes..
            }
        }
```